# Google Maps API v3 polyLine event remove

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am wanting to remove all mouseover and mouseclick events for a polyline in Google maps API v3
How to I achive this?

Comment: Make a list of the return values from addListener() as you call it, then loop through that list and call removeListener().

Comment: Thanks. But no. Defaults back to original event actions.

Answer (score 0):

[`google.maps.event.clearListeners()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#event) is the method you'll have to use, it removes all listeners for a particular event on a given instance.